# What is the correct formula and method of calculating standard deviation

Tags: java

// Correct the formula for standard deviation in this case. I don't know, what to do after getting the input from the user as the main problem is applying the formula correctly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class deviation {
    
  public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter value of n1, n2, n3, n4 and n5: ");
        double n1 = input.nextDouble();
        double n2 = input.nextDouble();
        double n3 = input.nextDouble();
        double n4 = input.nextDouble();
        double n5 = input.nextDouble();
        double mean = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5) / 5;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a question about maths/statistics basics, not about programming per se.

Comment: searched a lot but didn't find the solution related to this program

Comment: If your provided code `sum` is never declared. The first line to mention `sum` tries to read it's existing value, but it hasn't yet been declared or initialised.

Comment: The [wikipedia examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples) didn't help?

Comment: This was just a try to make the code run, i didn,t know about the formula

Comment: @Hulk i need to calculate this in java, so looking for suitable formula for java

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like a homework dump without any effort by the OP solving their homework on their own.

Comment: Please understand that this is not a free tutoring service where people sit down with you to go through your work. As others have pointed out, there is a lot of material explaining what standard deviation is. Look at that. Understand it. Compute it manually with a calculator. Then apply your knowledge into java code. If you hit a problem doing that, then you are welcome to ask about that. But do not come here and expect that *others* tell you the final result. Learning programming isnt about the final result. It is about **all** the steps I outlined here.

Answer (score 1):

Allthough it's hardcoded af, in your case this would be the solution:

```
double standardDeviation = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((n1-mean),2) + Math.pow((n2-mean),2) + Math.pow((n3-mean),2) + Math.pow((n4-mean),2) + Math.pow((n5-mean),2)) / 5);
```

Add this after caclculation of the mean and that's it. Don't forget to import **Math** library (`import java.lang.Math;`). But it's a very ugly way to code. You should change this and work with loops instead.